# SQL - 2 Primary Keys in 1 Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, primary-key

I have been researching this issue for several weeks now and despite the resources on this site and others, I cannot find any proper examples to lead me in the right direction. For an assignment, I am trying to create a table in SQL containing two PKs. I now understand that this isn't possible, but I cannot seem to understand why, mainly because it has been required of me. I attempted to change my code and separate the keys but I was told that was incorrect and to stick with the two PKs. Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is my current code for the table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE solds_ss /* This is creating the SOLDS table from the instance charts */
2      (
3           invoice_no     NUMBER(7)
4              CONSTRAINT invoice_no_pk PRIMARY KEY,
5              CONSTRAINT invoice_no_fk
6                 FOREIGN KEY (invoice_no)
7                 REFERENCES invoices_ss (invoice_no),
8           item_no     NUMBER(6)
9           CONSTRAINT item_no_pk PRIMARY KEY,
10             CONSTRAINT item_no_nn NOT NULL,
11             CONSTRAINT item_no_fk
12                FOREIGN KEY (item_no)
13                REFERENCES items_ss (item_no),
14          item_qty_sold     NUMBER(3)
15             CONSTRAINT item_qty_sold_nn NOT NULL,
16          item_price     NUMBER(6,2)
17             CONSTRAINT item_price_nn NOT NULL,
18          item_tracking_no     VARCHAR2(30)
19             CONSTRAINT item_tracking_no_nn NOT NULL
20     );
     CONSTRAINT item_no_pk PRIMARY KEY,
     *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-02260: table can have only one primary key
```

Comment: Primary key as the name says primary not concrete/multiple within a single table as a unique identifier with NOT NULL values but you can have as a combine clusture as primary key PRIMARY KEY(KEY1,KEY2)

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve though? You've stated the error you're getting with your proposed solution to problem X: "oracle won't let me have 2 primary keys", but you haven't actually stated what problem X is.. Oracle's refusal is non negotiable; you can never have 2 columns that are each a PK. Instead we need to know why you think you need 2 PK columns. If you want to respond "because person Z told me that's what I had to do", we really need to know why they told you that; some miscommunication between the two of you I think (I suspect you want a composite PK)

Comment: Find out what a PK is. You cannot want two. Why did you think you did?

Answer (score 4):

Following up on my comment, I suspect that what you want is a composite primary key - two columns that together make up the primary key/uniquely identify a row in the table. This is very different to "having two primary keys" - the value of each column might be repeated, but the combination of column 1 and column 2 must be unique:

```
InvoiceNo ItemNo
Inv1      Itm1
Inv1      Itm2
Inv2      Itm1
Inv2      Itm2
```

The table data above wouldn't be allowed if InvoiceNo was a primary key, or ItemNo was a primary key (each column contains repeated values when viewed in isolation), but is allowed if the primary key is defined as InvoiceNo and ItemNo in combination

Hence I think the sql you're looking for is more like:

```
 CREATE TABLE solds_ss /* This is creating the SOLDS table from the instance charts */
 (
      invoice_no     NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
      item_no     NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
      item_qty_sold     NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
      item_price     NUMBER(6,2) NOT NULL,
      item_tracking_no     VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,

         CONSTRAINT invoice_no_fk
            FOREIGN KEY (invoice_no)
            REFERENCES invoices_ss (invoice_no),
         CONSTRAINT item_no_fk
            FOREIGN KEY (item_no)
            REFERENCES items_ss (item_no),

         --composite pk
         CONSTRAINT solds_ss_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_no, item_no)

 );
```

Comment: I saw your comment and I tried tweaking my code to be composite but to no avail. Thank you for taking the time to provide me with an example. However, I am getting an error I've never received on line 2 (missing SELECT keyword) -- why would this be necessary?

Comment: Fixed up another few problems with your original code, try now

Comment: There was one more error at 8 (invalid identifier) for the item_no_nn NOT NULL, but I just cut that out and the table created. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yeah there were a few commas missing around the place; take a look at the layout above, and generally make your scripts like `CREATE TABLE(columns spec (comma separated), FK spec (comma separated), PK spec)` - people tend to lay them out like that rather than mixing columns and fk specs etc

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create two primary keys.  Primary keys have three properties:

- They are unique.
- They are non-NULL.
- There is only one per table.

It is the third property that prevents you from having two of them.  You can declare one column or groups of columns as both `unique` and `not null`. But only one such set of keys can be a *primary* key.

Answer (score 0):

> Primary key constraint designates **a column as the primary key** of a
>   table or view. A composite primary key designates **a combination of
>   columns as the primary key**.

Oracle doesn't allow multiple primary keys on a table or view. Look for *Primary key constraints* https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm

Answer (score 0):

A primary key has three properties:

1. It is not nullable.
2. It is unique.
3. It never changes.

So although Oracle will only allow you to define one primary key constraint per table, you can easily make a second, third, or fourth column with all the properties of a primary key by:

1. Give a NOT NULL constraint to the column(s).
2. Create a UNIQUE constraint on the column(s).
3. Swear up and down on a stack of Hershey bar wrappers (chocolate is sacred! :-) that you will never, ever, EVER change the value of any of the columns in your constraint. If you want this to be enforced you can do so using a trigger.

Comment: It's a good idea to make key values as stable as possible but it's not an absolute requirement that they *never* change.